# Transfer tokens inside a smart contract from an account to another account

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, action, c++

I need to write a simple function that would send tokens using a different account action. Exactly the same situation as in these questions: [one](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2454/transfer-eos-tokens-inside-a-smart-contract-from-an-account-to-another) and [two](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/270/how-to-do-an-action-in-a-contract-to-transfer-tokens-to-other-user-accounts-with)

But I have to use **not** eosio.token contract but my custom contract < transfercontract > that is similar to eosio.token.

My transfer code for < maincontract > looks like:

```
std::vector<permission_level> p;
p.push_back(permission_level{from, "active"_n});
action(p, "<transfercontract>"_n, "transfer"_n, std::make_tuple(from, to, quantity, std::string("Deduction test"))).send();
```

I used the command for adding eosio.code to the active permissions like here:

```
cleos set account permission <maincontract> active '{"threshold" : 1, "keys" : [{"key": "EOSpublicKey", "weight": 1}], "accounts" : [{"permission":{"actor":"<maincontract>","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[]}}' owner -p <maincontract>@owner
```

After that, I used my < maincontract > action with the following permissions:

```
cleos push action <maincontract> actionname '["from","to", "quantity"]' -p from
```

Actually, I've tried several different options for permissions, but nothing worked.

Please, help me resolve it.

I did not set the permissions correctly when performing a transaction? or incorrectly added additional permissions for the account?

**UPDATE:**

The execution:

```
cleos push action crowdfledger customaction '["forbanpirate","anotheraccount","1.000 TKN"]' -p forbanpirate
```

The crowdfledger contract tries to use `<transferaccount >::transfer(forbanpirate, anotheraccount, 1.0000 TKN)` inside.

The error:

```
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority 
'{"actor":"forbanpirate","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions 
[{"actor":"crowdfledger","permission":"eosio.code"}], provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms
```

pending console output:

Comment: Provide the exactly error message you're experiencing and... `cleos push action <maincontract> actionname '["from","to", "quantity"]' -p from` should they have a memo included in parameters?

Comment: I've added the error into the post. No, the memo is hardcoded, so there is no need to send it. @JohnWilliamson

Comment: Add the private key of your account on which your token smart contract is deployed into you wallet.

Comment: @RidhamCPP All required private keys are imported into the wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue, basically inline transactions cannot use the active key on the users behalf, but there are work arounds to getting the functionality done.

One such method is to have the user add a permission to the contract code to act on their behalf. Another is to use listeners for say a transfer and only act if the transfer meets a certain requirement, such as a transfer to the contract with a memo of "do this action". There are probably other methods as well.

see more here:
[Require inline action be sent by contract, and not account](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/require-inline-action-be-sent-by-contract-and-not-account)